# for loop in python to color multiple cells in excel

Tags: python, excel, format

Playing with python and I want to take my color and add it to several cells at once, I am sure I am supposed to use a for loop to do it but not sure how to go about it:

Here is my code now:

```
import openpyxl
import xlrd
import xlwt
import time

#Big Header Font Format
font0 = xlwt.Font()
font0.name = 'Times New Roman'
font0.bold = True
font0.height = 400
style0 = xlwt.XFStyle()
style0.font = font0


#Little Header Font Format
font1 = xlwt.Font()
font1.name = 'Times New Roman'
font1.bold = True
font1.height = 240
style1 = xlwt.XFStyle()
style1.font = font1

#Background color format blue
style2 = xlwt.XFStyle()
pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['blue']
style2.pattern = pattern

#Background color format
style3 = xlwt.XFStyle()
pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['light_blue']
style3.pattern = pattern

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Z:\Public\Safety\SafetyDataPullProject\TestFile.xlsx')
type(wb)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")



sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")
sheet1.write(0, 0, "BFI4 AM CARE EOS REPORT", style0, style3)
sheet1.write(0, 6,(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")), style0)
sheet1.write(1, 0, 'Encounter Type', style1)
sheet1.write(1, 3, "Day Shift", style1)
sheet1.write(1, 4, "Night Shift", style1)
sheet1.write(1, 5, "Totals", style1)
sheet1.write(1, 6, "WTD", style1)
```

As a preemptive strike if I were to add in my cell formatting into the my
    sheet1.write

I get a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/python things/data3.py", line 45, in <module>
sheet1.write(0, 0, "BFI4 AM CARE EOS REPORT", style0, style3)
TypeError: write() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

I was wondering how to work around this ? Being if I were to try and add a seperate line of code for the same shell it will not let me overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not provide more than one style to the `write` function.

However, You can use `style0` values in `style3` :

```
#Background color format
style3 = xlwt.XFStyle()

# update style0 values
style3.font = style0.font
# update custom values
pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['light_blue']
style3.pattern = pattern
...
sheet1.write(0, 0, "BFI4 AM CARE EOS REPORT", style3)
```

Comment: Oh okay, so I would have the combine them then ?